# Field Collection : Query to get the node id by sending a value of a field collection field value

Tags: nodes, entities

- I am having a field collection in a content type called 'client'.
  There are,

  1. Client name
  2. Email
  3. Mobile
  4. Address 1
  5. Address 2
  6. Address 3
  7. etc..
     as fields. That's it in the client content type.
- I am having another content type which basically has a textfield and a dropdown list
- The texfield allows to enter a client's name
- Once the client's name is filled in the textfield the dropdown list should be filled with  client's addresses
- So what I am trying to do here is, programmatically generate the dropdown options by sending the client's name and getting their relevant addresses which was saved using the client content type.
- I'm quite confused with DB structure for field collection values.

Would be great if you can help ASAP

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [Field Collection Values](http://drupal.org/node/1477202)

As it says, try

> To get the values of the individual field items call the entity_load
>   function:

```
<?php
  $node25 = node_load(25);
  $track_1 = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($node25->field_track[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']));
  $track_2 = entity_load('field_collection_item', array($node25->field_track[LANGUAGE_NONE][1]['value']));
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete working example you can just copy and paste but it has the elements you need (I can't do it exact as I don't know all your field names etc.).

```
// This should be set to the client name that has been entered into the client name field.
$client_name = 'John Doe';
// Get field collection items with the given client name.
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'field_collection_item')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'FIELD_COLLECTION_NAME')
  ->fieldCondition('CLIENT_NAME_FIELD_ID', 'value', $client_name);

$result = $query->execute();

$field_collection_items = array();
if (isset($result['field_collection_item'])) {
  $field_collection_item_ids = array_keys($result['field_collection_item']);
  $field_collection_items = field_collection_item_load_multiple($field_collection_item_ids);
}

// If you expect there to only ever be one field collection item for each name, do this:
// From your description it seems like you only want to deal with a single one.
// This will be your client field collection item.
$client_field_collection_item = reset($field_collection_items);

// Otherwise, loop through the items that match the name and do something with each one.
// However, based on your question I will stick with the above single item.
foreach ($field_collection_items as $field_collection_item) {
  // Do something with each $field_collection_item here.
}

// To get the value of one of the fields of the field collection item, do this:
$lang = field_language('field_collection_item', $client_field_collection_item, 'FIELD_NAME');
$address1 = '';
if (!empty($client_field_collection_item[$lang][0])) {
  $address1 = $client_field_collection_item[$lang][0]['value'];
}
```